# Trace the maze to reach from source to goal

Tags: c++, recursion, maze

I am trying to implement a solution to a problem wherein I need to find a path in a maze recursively from source to goal.

Suppose this is the maze : 

`S X X X X X 
. . . . . X 
X . X X X X 
X . X X X X 
. . . X . G 
X X . . . X`

where

X- blocked path

.- Open path

S- Start

G -Goal

I have written following code to implement the solution but it gives me a segmentation fault.
I would be glad if someone could suggest me where I am doing it wrong.

My solution is

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void printGrid(char grid[6][6])
{
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            cout<<grid[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}

bool isValidPoint(char grid[6][6],int x,int y)
{   
    if(x<0 || x>5 || y<0 || y>5)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(grid[x][y]=='X')
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool traceMaze(char grid[6][6],int x,int y)
{
    if(!isValidPoint(grid,x,y))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(grid[x][y]=='G')
    {
        return true;
    }

    grid[x][y] = '+';

    if(traceMaze(grid,x-1,y)){return true;}
    if(traceMaze(grid,x,y+1)){return true;}
    if(traceMaze(grid,x+1,y)){return true;}
    if(traceMaze(grid,x,y-1)){return true;}

    grid[x][y] = '.';

    return false;

}


int main()
{
    char grid[6][6] = {{'S','X','X','X','X','X'},{'.','.','.','.','.','X'},{'X','.','X','X','X','X'},{'X','.','X','X','X','X'},{'.','.','.','X','.','G'},{'X','X','.','.','.','X'}};
    cout<<"Initial grid is as follows :\n";
    printGrid(grid);
    cout<<"\nStarting at : (0,0)\nTracing the path to the Goal\n";
    cout<<traceMaze(grid,0,0)<<"\n";
    cout<<"\nFinal grid is as follows :\n";
    printGrid(grid);
    return 0;
}
```

PS : I am assuming the size of maze to be 6X6...

```
Correct Solution :
```

I didn't had any check for the '+' that I was putting through to see the final traced path.

So now I have applied a check there and the `isValidPoint` function transformed into :

```
bool isValidPoint(char grid[6][6],int x,int y)
{   
    if(x<0 || x>5 || y<0 || y>5)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(grid[x][y]=='X' || grid[x][y]=='+')
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thank you for your help guys :)

I got this question a full time interview last year.

Comment: My purpose of adding '+' here is to just see the traced path, which would be reflected in the printGrid() call before return 0;

Comment: A debugger and a few minutes of your time would expose your fault nearly immediately. Likewise with a `std::cerr` dump of your `x` and `y` values immediately **before** using them to dereference your maze for reading/writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to stop your traceMaze function from recursing infinitely. i.e. It will go from one grid point to the next and then back to the original.

The easiest fix would be to not treat and point with a "+" in it as a valid point to go into (as you have already been there in this path).

Comment: I have the base cases in isValidPoint & the if check with value=='G'

Is that not enough?

Comment: Ohh I got it , should I put in a check for '+' as well or should I replace it with a 'X'?

Answer (score 0):

The Dark's answer is valid in my opinion.

Your search is startting from 0,0. Then it goes to 0,1, and from there it goes back to 0,0, and again to 0,1... You should mark squares you have already visited and not go there again. '+' is fine, but you shouldn't clear it once you have set it, and you should check it in isValidPoint.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is a depth-first traversal of the maze. You're changing a `.` with a `+` to keep track of the visited points, but you're changing them to a `.` again when done. This is the problem.

Suppose `A` and `B` are adjacent cells of the maze. When you're traversing `A`, you change `A` to a `+` and recursively traverse its neighbors (including `B`), then change `A` to a `.` again. Then, when you're traversing `B`, `A` is a `.`, so you traverse `A` from `B` again, which is not necessary.

That's why the recursion never ends, and you're getting a segmentation fault.

One way to solve this is to keep a separate 6x6 array to keep track of the visited points. When you're done with a cell (i.e. traversed all possible paths from that cell), mark it as a 'visited' one, and never visit a visited cell again.

Comment: yea that is an option but it would increase space complexity of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote down your maze on a sheet of paper and tried the algorithm by hand, and got stuck at x=2, y=1 where your algorithm wanted to go back to x=1,y=1, returning to the state before. This state of course proceeds into the aforementioned state and an infinite loop is created. An important rule of recursive programming is to always make sure all function calls have all execution paths end up in a return call (or similar)

If you want to get ballsy on the subject, I would suggest you look into [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) solving using for example [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).